# How to transform armature via other object's data?

Tags: scripting

I want to transform an armature / skeleton of a 3D model in blender via collected data from another model. As I am new to blender I have no clue what the input data would be and how I would transform or even select the armature in blender, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Maybe your Problem is that you aren't in edit mode when you try to do the transforms of the individual bones? At least do that if you want to "permanently" modify the location. If you only want to change the "pose" of the bones, you'll need use pose mode to do that. (Maybe i misunderstood and you want to do the tranforming automatically by writing a python script with some input data format like .txt?)

Comment: Yes, I want to transform an existing skeleton in Blender with a python script to a skeleton I already have the data of which is loaded by the python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example by modifying `bpy.context.object.data.edit_bones.head` when in edit mode you can change the position of the bone head. Here is a code sample how this could be used to translate the bones of a selected armature object with three bones:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')


myObject = bpy.context.object ##Active Selected Object

##### Make a Matrix with your translation values 
myBoneTranformMatrix = [  [0,0,0],    ##Head Bone0
                          [0,0,1],    ##Head Bone1 (=Tail Bone0)
                          [1,2,3],    ##Head Bone2 
                          [4,5,6]  ]  ##Tail of the last bone...   


if myObject.type == 'ARMATURE':
    myArmature = myObject.data

    boneCounter=0 
    for currentBone in myArmature.edit_bones:
        currentBone.head = myBoneTranformMatrix[boneCounter]
        currentBone.tail = myBoneTranformMatrix[boneCounter+1]
        boneCounter+=1


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Happy Blending! :)